# Is it possible to block a specific website for a specific network in windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, internet, blocking

Suppose I have two wifi networks N1 and N2.

My targeted Website is **Abcd.com**

Now I want my PC not to be able to access the site **abcd.com** when I connect to the N1 network. But the PC will be able to access the site **abced.com** when I am connected to the network N2.

Please keep in mind that I can't block the site from the router. I have to block it from my PC.